# How to pass multiple parameters in a URL in php?

Tags: php, html

I want to pass multiple parameters to a URL using post method. I created a form wherein the user could enter the values and submit the form and then it opens a new page where the URL is displayed to be clicked to process the transaction with the given parameters.

Here, I'm unable to finish this task. I don't know where I'm doing the mistake, but the URL is not getting correctly.

Kindly help me fix this issue please.
Test.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="Test.php" method="POST">
Mobile Number: <input type="text" name="mNum"><br>
Recepient ID: <input type="text" name="resID"><br>
Bank A/c Number: <input type="text" name="acNum"><br>
Amount: <input type="text" name="amt"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.php

```
<html>
<body>
Confirm?<br><br>
<a href="http://example.com/money-api/transaction-now?api_token=3e5R4a9U6T7TfypoNvqKv&mobile_number=<?php echo $_POST["mNum"]; ?>&receipient_id=<?php echo $_POST["resID"]; ?>&bank_account=<?php echo $_POST["acNum"]; ?>&amount=<?php echo $_POST["amt"]; ?>&channel=1&client_id=11221106">CONFIRM</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please put your actual html code

Comment: If you want the submitted parameters to appear in the URL, then you use the `GET` method instead of `POST`.

Comment: If you like a query string as stated above then you should *not* use `POST` instead you should use `GET` as the form method `<form method="GET"` ...

Comment: Shall I replace all the places where post was put with get? @mistermartin

Comment: Shall I replace all the places where post was put with get? @Cyclone

Comment: @vIJAy - What do you mean? You just have one form? `<form action="Test.php" method="GET">` should be enough. Then in your `Test.php` file you need to replace every occurance of `$_POST` with `$_GET`

Comment: @Cyclone - One form is enough for this requirement. But still I'm not getting the URL correctly

Comment: @vIJAy - The above should work as is but you have forgot to quote your link in `Test.php` correctly: `<a href="...">text</a>`. Right now you are not outputting the link correctly.

Comment: @Cyclone - I just corrected it now. But still it is not showing the URL correctly. it is showing like this:  
&receipient_id=&bank_account=&amount=&channel=1&client_id=11221106>CONFIRM

Comment: @Cyclone - The URL formed like this:
http://example.com/money-api/transaction-now?api_token=3e5R4a9U6T7TfypoNvqKv&mobile_number=%3C?php

Comment: And this is most likely because you are forgetting the quotes around the url i.e `<a href="http://www.google.com">TEST</a>` notice the double quotes `"`

Comment: @Cyclone - Thank you. I corrected that just now only. But still the URL is not forming in full length my friend. It is showing up only a partial URL:
http://example.com/money-api/transaction-now?api_token=3e5R4a9U6T7TfypoNvqKv&mobile_number=<?php echo $_POST[

and again showing up the CONFIRM hyperlink like this only:
&receipient_id=&bank_account=&amount=&channel=1&client_id=11221106">CONFIRM

Comment: @Cyclone - Thank you. I corrected that just now only. But still the URL is not forming in full length my friend. It is showing up only a partial URL: example.com/money-api/… echo $_GET[ and again showing up the CONFIRM hyperlink like this only: &receipient_id=&bank_account=&amount=&channel=1&client_id=11221106">CONFIRM

Comment: @Cyclone - Thanks so much. Its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. The only issues are
1. Missed double quotes in the URL (now corrected).
2. By mistake, tested the code on normal web browser on the local machine instead of doing it on the server.

That's all.